# Displaying data table in shiny app, columns displayed conditional on checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm trying to render a Data table in a shiny app. When I pass it through without any conditional arguments it displays just fine. A problem arises when I try to make the displayed variables conditional on input from a checkBoxGroup widget.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(pander)
library(plyr)

load("data/ages.data.rda")
load("data/test.data.rda")
load("data/refine.data.rda")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$tafla.gogn <- renderDataTable({

dataset <- switch(input$data,
                  "study1" = ages.data,
                  "study2" = test.data
                 )
dataset[,input$breytur, drop = F]
 }, options=list(pageLength=10, searchDelay=500))

})
```

## ui.R

```
shinyUI(navbarPage(img(src="logo.png"), theme="bootstrap.css",        collapsible=T, windowTitle="My research",
tabPanel("Tables",
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    #The problem arises when I try to use this widget, I suspect it has something to do with me calling the output$dataset.
    checkboxGroupInput("breytur", label="Hvaða dálka viltu sjá?", choices =  names("output$dataset"), selected = names("output$dataset")) 
  ),
  mainPanel(        
     h2("Selected data"),
     dataTableOutput("tafla.gogn")

     )
   )
   ))
  ))
```

When I run the app I get the error:
    Listening on [deleted]
    Error in mapply(ids, choices, names(choices), FUN = function(id, value,  : 
      zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length
    Error in mapply(ids, choices, names(choices), FUN = function(id, value,  : 
      zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

The data is loaded from .rda files as data.frames from within the data folder in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similar thing I did via   creating the CheckboxGroupInput in the server script and rendering the UI . 
[I wanted to share a way how you can achieve this -was lazy enough to add code]
To answer with a Code :

Server.r :

```
  ages.data <- load("data/ages.data.rda")
  test.data <- load("data/test.data.rda")
  data_sets <- c("ages.data","test.data")

  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Dataset",label = "choose a dataset",as.list(data_sets))

  })

  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$Dataset))
      return()


    dat <- get(input$Dataset)
    colnames <- names(dat)


   checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)





  })
```

ui.r

```
    shinyUI(navbarPage(img(src="logo.png"), theme="bootstrap.css",        collapsible=T, windowTitle="My research",
tabPanel("Tables",
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
   uiOutput("choose_dataset"),
   uiOutput("choose_columns") 
  ),
```

Comment: It's been a while and I've long since solved this.
Ran into this answer while looking through my catalogue of questions and noticed I had gotten an answer I hadn't looked at.
Upvoted and marked this one since looking at the code it would solve my problem. Thank you!